# Save error : Expecting right curly bracket,foubnd '<EOF>' at line 63

Tags: apex, class

```
public class Case_Automated_Escalation_Arkansas{
    public static void beforeTriggerCall(List<Case> listCase){
        for(Case cs : listCase){
            String queueName ='';

                if(cs.Status == 'Action - Automated Escalation' && (cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'Computer - Office' 
                || cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'Email'
                || cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'Telephone'
                || cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'Software (Computer)'
                || cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'Printing / Imaging'
                || cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'Outage'
                || cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'Network'
                || cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'Mobile Device - User Owned'
                || cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'LMS') 
                ){
                    queueName = 'Eversity - Onsite IT';
                }

                if(cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'ERP' 
                && (cs.Ticket_Type__c == 'Access / Permissions' 
                || cs.Ticket_Type__c == 'Login' 
                || cs.Ticket_Type__C == 'Other'
                || cs.Ticket_Type__C == 'Reporting (ERP)'
                || cs.Ticket_Type__C == 'Staff Dept / Role (ERP)' 
                || cs.Ticket_Type__C == 'Student (ERP)') 
                && cs.Status = 'Action - Automated Escalation'){
                    queueName = 'Eversity - Onsite Records Group';
                }

              if(cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'General Information' && cs.Ticket_Type__c == 'Admissions' && cs.Status == 'Action - Automated Escalation'){
                queueName = 'Eversity - Admissions';
               }

              if(cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'General Information' && cs.Ticket_Type__c == 'Financial Aid' && cs.Status == 'Action - Automated Escalation'){
                queueName = 'Eversity - Financial Aid';
         }       

               if(cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'General Information' && cs.Ticket_Type__c == 'Advising' && cs.Status == 'Action - Automated Escalation'){
                queueName = 'Eversity - Advising';
               }
                          if(cs.Ticket_Category__c == 'Computer - User Owned' && cs.Status == 'Action - Automated Escalation'){
                cs.Status='Closed Successful';

         }
                if(UtilityController.mapQueue.containsKey(queueName)){
                cs.OwnerId = UtilityController.mapQueue.get(queueName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider using `Set.contains` to avoid these long `||` chains.

Comment: Some suggestions on how to find the problem: 1) indent your code consistently; 2) comment out blocks of code until the code compiles and then review those commented out people; 3) as Adrian suggests make the code cleaner. The code you have posted is only 50 lines long.

Comment: That's about 50 lines of code. Maybe you missed something in creating the question. Otherwise it seems odd that the error would be on line 63.

Comment: I'd make `queueName` a formula field returning String value - much easier to maintain tweak the logic.

Answer (score 6):

I cleaned it up according to the Google Style Guide and added some constant Strings, Sets and a Map to simplify your if statements.

This allows these strings to be used as references - notice that they're all public, which means you can reference them from other classes and you only have to ever change the value in one place. You can add new general information ticket types and queues just by modifying the Map. You can can do the same with escalation ticket categories.

I went full zealotry on turning all 'Magic Strings' into constants, mostly because I wanted to illustrate the different ways that you can utilize constants to simplify maintenance of your code. Notice it's very easy to follow along with the code blocks to know if you have made a mistake in indentation or have mismatched brackets.

```
public class Case_Automated_Escalation_Arkansas {
    public static final Set<String> ERP_TICKET_TYPES = new Set<String>{'Computer - Office', 'Email', 'Telephone', 'Software (Computer)', 'Printing / Imaging', 'Outage', 'Network', 'Mobile Device - User Owned', 'LMS'};
    public static final Set<String> AUTOMATED_ESCALATION_TICKET_CATEGORIES = new Set<String>{'Computer - Office', 'Email', 'Telephone', 'Software (Computer)', 'Printing / Imaging', 'Outage', 'Network', 'Mobile Device - User Owned', 'LMS'};
    public static final Map<String, String> GENERAL_INFORMATION_QUEUE_MAP = new Map<String, String>{'Admissions' => 'Eversity - Admissions', 'Financial Aid' => 'Eversity - Financial Aid', 'Advising' => 'Eversity - Advising'};
    public static final String GENERAL_INFORMATION = 'General Information';
    public static final String AUTOMATED_ESCALATION = 'Action - Automated Escalation';
    public static final String EVERSITY_ONSITE_IT = 'Eversity - Onsite IT';
    public static final String EVERSITY_ONSITE_RECORDS_GROUP = 'Eversity - Onsite Records Group';
    public static final String COMPUTER_USER_OWNED = 'Computer - User Owned';
    public static final String CLOSED_SUCCESSFUL = 'Closed Successful';
    public static final String ERP = 'ERP';

    public static void beforeTriggerCall(List<Case> listCase) {
        for (Case cs : listCase) {
            String queueName ='';
            if (cs.Status == AUTOMATED_ESCALATION) {
                if (AUTOMATED_ESCALATION_TICKET_CATEGORIES.contains(cs.Ticket_Category__c)) {
                    queueName = EVERSITY_ONSITE_IT;
                } else if (cs.Ticket_Category__c == ERP && ERP_TICKET_TYPES.contains(cs.Ticket_Type__c)) {
                    queueName = EVERSITY_ONSITE_RECORDS_GROUP;
                } else if (cs.Ticket_Category__c == COMPUTER_USER_OWNED) {
                    cs.Status = CLOSED_SUCCESSFUL;
                } else if (cs.Ticket_Category__c == GENERAL_INFORMATION && GENERAL_INFORMATION_QUEUE_MAP.containsKey(cs.Ticket_Type__c)) {
                    queueName = GENERAL_INFORMATION_QUEUE_MAP.get(cs.Ticket_Type__c);
                }     
            }
            if (UtilityController.mapQueue.containsKey(queueName)) {
                cs.OwnerId = UtilityController.mapQueue.get(queueName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd upvote if I hadn't run out for the day. That's a lot of work and a nice result.

Comment: Also, way to redeem the question. Now I feel compelled to retract my close vote. :P

Comment: upvoting on @AdrianLarson  behalf

Comment: Daily vote cap lifted. :) I remembered to come back and vote.